# How to combine two functions with the same logic but different input parameters?

Tags: python

I have a function that will be used under different modules. There are two functions that take different arguments but the function logic is similar. I am trying to unite func1 and func2  functions into one.

Is there a way I can use the python functionality to handle this case?

`func1`

```
def create_data_file_removed_duplicate_item(packing_data, output_dir, warehouse_name, date, model_type):

    packing_data = packing_data.drop_duplicates(subset='item_id', keep="last")
    # create non duplicate item data file
    make_directory(output_dir)
    file_name_for_non_duplicate \
        = ap_conf.file_name_of_processed_data_non_duplicate_item\
        .format(warehouse_name=warehouse_name, date=date, model_type=model_type)
    file_path_for_non_duplicate = output_dir + file_name_for_non_duplicate
    packing_data.to_csv(file_path_for_non_duplicate, sep="\t", header=False, index=False)

    return file_path_for_non_duplicate
```

`func2`:

```
def create_data_file_without_duplicate_item(packing_data, output_dir, model_type):

    packing_data = packing_data.drop_duplicates(subset='item_id', keep="last")

    # create non-duplicate item data file

    make_directory(output_dir)
    file_name_for_non_duplicate \
        = ap_conf.file_name_of_processed_data_aggregated_warehouse_non_duplicate_item \
        .format(model_type=model_type)
    file_path_for_non_duplicate = output_dir + file_name_for_non_duplicate
    packing_data.to_csv(file_path_for_non_duplicate, sep="\t", header=False, index=False)

    logger.info('data count after removing duplicates: ' + str(len(packing_data)))
    return file_path_for_non_duplicate
```

Comment: Move `warehouse_name` and `date` to the end of the parameter list and make them optional.  Then check if they are set inside the method.  Something like `create_data_file_without_duplicate_item(packing_data, output_dir, model_type, warehouse_name=None, date=None)`.

Comment: You can also just call one function from the other, though I can't necessarily speak to whether or not that is good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

- You can pass `warehouse_name` as default parameter.
- Make a conditional call to `file_name_for_non_duplicate` and `logger.info`.

```
#New Func


def create_data_file_removed_duplicate_item(packing_data, output_dir,                                                
                                            model_type, warehouse_name = None, date = None):

    packing_data = packing_data.drop_duplicates(subset='item_id', keep="last")
    # create non duplicate item data file
    make_directory(output_dir)
    if warehouse_name:
        file_name_for_non_duplicate \
            = ap_conf.file_name_of_processed_data_non_duplicate_item\
            .format(warehouse_name=warehouse_name, date=date, model_type=model_type)
    else :
        file_name_for_non_duplicate \
            = ap_conf.file_name_of_processed_data_aggregated_warehouse_non_duplicate_item \
            .format(model_type=model_type)

    file_path_for_non_duplicate = output_dir + file_name_for_non_duplicate
    packing_data.to_csv(file_path_for_non_duplicate, sep="\t", header=False, index=False)

    if not warehouse_name:
        logger.info(
            'data count after removing duplicates: ' + str(len(packing_data)))

    return file_path_for_non_duplicate
```

Comment: Can I use`warehouse_name = None, date=None` instead? Actually, warehouse_name and date both are required in one case and not required in the else part.

Comment: Don't optional parameters have to be at the end of the list?

Comment: Right! both have to be at the end

Comment: @sam you can use warehouse_name = None, date=None.  If string is empty or None it will return False. Also, Please correct that optional parameters should be at the end of the list.

Comment: It should be like `if warehouse_name and date:`
Right?